# Magento - pass a variable from Controller to checkout temaplte

Tags: magento, variables, controller

I've read the other posts about this subject and tried loads of things but cant get a Variable from my controller file to the Checkout. I have very little experience with creating modules so followed a guide to create the following

app ▸ code ▸ local ▸ Creare ▸ AgeRestricted ▸ etc ▸ config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creare_AgeRestricted>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Creare_AgeRestricted>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <age_restricted>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>AgeRestricted/observer</class>
                        <method>AgeRestricted</method>
                    </age_restricted>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events> 
        <models>
            <AgeRestricted>
                <class>Creare_AgeRestricted_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>agerestricted_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </AgeRestricted>
        </models>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <item>
                    <product_attributes>
                        <age_restricted/>
                    </product_attributes>
                </item>
            </quote>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

Macintosh HD ▸ WWW-local ▸ dexam ▸ htdocs_live ▸ app ▸ code ▸ local ▸ Creare ▸ AgeRestricted ▸ Model ▸ Observer.php

```
<?php

class Creare_AgeRestricted_Model_Observer
{
    public function AgeRestricted(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
    Mage::register('feedback', $AgeRestricted);
       $event           = $observer->getEvent();
           $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
           $result          = $event->getResult();
       $AgeRestricted        = false;

        foreach (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as     $item)
        {
            if($item->getProduct()->getAgeRestricted()){
               $AgeRestricted = true;
             }

        }

    }

}
```

Notice I added the line:

```
Mage::register('feedback', $AgeRestricted);
```

then im trying to call this with:

```
echo Mage::registry('feedback');
```

in file:
app/design/frontend/dexam/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

but it displays nothing at all. I've tested the location in payment.phtml is working.. my test text appears but 'feedback' is not calling the $AgeRestricted.

I tried echo $AgeRestricted; in my controller, which echo'd lots of '1's at the top of my screen so I can see the variable contains the true value.

How can I call $AgeRestricted in payment.phtml?

Many thanks!!
Daz

Comment: You have to put Mage::register('feedback', $AgeRestricted); after the initialization of the variable $AgeRestricted = false;

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but i'm getting the error - Mage registry key "feedback" already exists. I'm certain its because the same code is running over and over. I tried the if statment below too but that also gives the key already exists error.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

class Creare_AgeRestricted_Model_Observer
{
    public function AgeRestricted(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
    
       $event           = $observer->getEvent();
           $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
           $result          = $event->getResult();
       $AgeRestricted        = false;

        foreach (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as     $item)
        {
            if($item->getProduct()->getAgeRestricted()){
               $AgeRestricted = true;
             }

        }

    if(!Mage::register('feedback')){
       Mage::register('feedback', $AgeRestricted); // put this line here after all processing
    }

    }

}
```

Hope this will help you out

Comment: This gives this error when loading the checkout: - Mage registry key "feedback" already exists

Comment: did you check that this Mage::register('feedback', $AgeRestricted); is only one time in Observer.php also you need to put if condition to check whether variable register or not

Comment: This is the only time it calls in Observer.php. (Its the same code as supplied above. I know that when I echo $AgeRestricted it gives lots of '1's so its obviously running several times. How can I register the Variable, then update its value on every subsequent attempt?

Comment: I've added the if statement that you added above, but still giving the error - Mage registry key "feedback" already exists
.

Comment: are you sure that this code not present else where Mage::register('feedback', $AgeRestricted) or do clearing cache and log file after code edit

Comment: This is the first time I've written this module so Im pretty sure Mage::register('feedback', $AgeRestricted) is not anywhere else. I've changed to Mage::register('feedback123456', $AgeRestricted) to make it specific. Now the error shows - Mage registry key "feedback123456" already exists. Also Deleted contents of cache and reports folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento checkout sessions to set the value from the observer to payment file

```
<?php

class Creare_AgeRestricted_Model_Observer
{
    public function AgeRestricted(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

       $event           = $observer->getEvent();
           $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
           $result          = $event->getResult();
       $AgeRestricted        = false;

        foreach (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as     $item)
        {
            if($item->getProduct()->getAgeRestricted()){
               $AgeRestricted = true;
             }

        }

    if($AgeRestricted){
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setRestictedAge($AgeRestricted);
    }

    }

}
```

In your payment.phtml

```
<?php $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');?>
<?php echo $session->getRestrictedAge();?>
```